# completely destroy marker on gmap3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, jquery-gmap3

I am trying to let a user drop up to 10 markers and remove them onClick.  I also have it updating a "div" with the coordinates of the markers on the map when a user adds a marker or drags.  I have everything working except for when the user deletes a marker, it's still seems to be on the map when I loop through the markers.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/WRyrJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/WRyrJ/)

Code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      var markerCount = 0;

        $("#test1").gmap3({
            map: {
                options: {
                    center: [-2.2214281090541204, -78.695068359375],
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControl: true,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
                    },
                    navigationControl: true,
                    scrollwheel: true,
                    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                    streetViewControl: false,

                },
                events: {


                    click: function (map, event) {

                        if(markerCount < 10){


                        $(this).gmap3(

                           {
                               marker: {
                                   latLng: event.latLng,
                                   options:{
                                    draggable: true,
                                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                     },



                                    events: {
                                    click: function(marker) {

                                     marker.setMap(map);
                                     marker.setMap(null);
                                     marker = null;
                                     delete marker;
                                     console.log(marker); 

                                     markerCount--;
                                         },

                                    dragend: function(marker) {
                                    $("#inputArray").empty();

                           setTimeout(function(){
                           var markers = $("#test1").gmap3({
                             get: {
                             all: true
                             }
                             });

                             $.each(markers, function(i, marker){

                             $("#inputArray").append('<p>{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() +', '+ '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() +'},'+'</p>');
                             });
                             }, 400);



                                         }


                                      },


                                   },


                              });

                           markerCount++;

                           $("#inputArray").empty();

                           setTimeout(function(){
                           var markers = $("#test1").gmap3({
                             get: {
                             all: true
                             }
                             });

                             $.each(markers, function(i, marker){

                             $("#inputArray").append('<p>{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() +', '+ '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() +'},'+'</p>');
                             });
                             }, 400);

                        }

                        else{
                             return false;
                         }; 

                    }
                }
            }
        });

     });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of thing is maybe less than straightforward in gmap3. You need a slightly different mindset compared with that required for the direct google.maps API.

Thee main poitns :

- You need to provide the markers with an id, name or tag
- You need to remove the marker with `clear`
- You need to make judicious use of callbacks (the gmap3 way).

Here's your code unravelled into a set of functions, with the necessary fixes applied

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var mapOpts = {
        center: [-2.2214281090541204, -78.695068359375],
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
    };
    function genId() {
        return '' + (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    function addMarker(map, event) {
        if (markerCount < 10) {
            var uid = genId();
            $(this).gmap3({
                marker: {
                    latLng: event.latLng,
                    options: {
                        draggable: true,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            clearMarker(uid);
                        },
                        dragend: listMarkers
                    },
                    id: uid
                }
            });
            markerCount++;
            listMarkers();
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    }
    function listMarkers() {
        $("#test1").gmap3({
            get: {
                all: true,
                callback: function(results) {
                    $("#inputArray").empty();
                    $.each(results, function (i, marker) {
                        $("#inputArray").append('<p>{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '</p>');
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function clearMarker(uid) {
        $('#test1').gmap3({
            clear: {
                id: uid,
                callback: function() {
                    listMarkers();
                    markerCount--;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var markerCount = 0;

    $("#test1").gmap3({
        map: {
            options: mapOpts,
            events: {
                click: addMarker
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/su7uT/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking at the "clear" function the whole time but noticed It couldn't clear a specific marker without an Id,tag or name.  I was struggling with the part on a making dynmaic id for each marker.  Hats off to you sir.  The action setMap(null) is a dirty way of clearing a marker knowing that it just destroys the overlay.  Could you give me some good references to learn more documentation on gmap3?

Comment: My main reference is the [gmap3 Documentation](http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/). As with anything else, I also google specific issues and often end up back in the Documentation or in StackOverflow. Your question was actually quite tricky. I found the documentation to be well laced with examples but relatively poor at explaining the general principles. It led me down several blind alleys before hitting on the solution. Finally it was a question of tidying up lots of scrappy code in the fiddle. Like many folks here on SO, I don't always know the answers but enjoy working out solutions.